# Como usar ngIf para ocultar Links?

Tags: angular

Vou dizer diretamente o que estou precisando, depois vou detalhar mais o meu problema.

**Eu preciso ocultar esse link do editar, como posso fazer isso com ngIF?**

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
        <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
        <div class="siderbar-admin" data-simple-id="simples-nav-stacked">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked nav-pills-stacked-example">

                <li role="presentation" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
                  <a [routerLink]="['list-restaurant']">Lista</a>

                </li>
                <li role="presentation" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" >
                    <a [routerLink]="['add-restaurant']" >Adicionar</a>

                </li>
                <li role="presentation" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
                     <a [routerLink]="['Edit/:id']" >Editar</a>

                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-lg-8">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
```

Vamos para explicação detalhada, observem a imagem abaixo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como você podem perceber existe um link para **lista**, **adicionar** e **editar**, porém quando saio do **lista** para o Link **editar** sem clicar no botão editar da pagina **lista**  o sistema gera um erro, isso porque o formulário de **editar**  foi carregado sem o id do registro. Para evitar esses problemas seria importante que o Link **editar** fosse mostrando somente quando o usuário clicasse no botão editar na pagina de **lista**, vou tentar explicar novamente.

Como preciso que o sistema se comporte ?

Na tela abaixo mostre somente **lista** e **adicionar**, e somente mostre o link editar quando o usuário navegar até a pagina **lista** e clicar no botão editar.

Eu sei o funcionamento teórico do **ngIF** olhando pela documentação, mas apesar de tudo a documentação não me fez ter ideias de como resolver isso.

[ESSE É O MEU REPOSITÓRIO](https://github.com/wladyband/angular-sistema-vendas/tree/master/src/app/admin)

Comment: Não sei se entendi muito bem.. não seria só remover o editar ali da lista? A edição, ao meu ver, só poderia surgir quando o usuário clicasse no botão editar em um registro já existente

Comment: Se você quer ocultar, um ngShow/ngHide seriam mais apropriados, ou até um `[hidden]` no seu caso:  `[hidden]="!mostarEditar"`, dai só mudar o valor de "mostrarEditar" para exibir/ocultar o link

Comment: É isso mesmo @Pedro quando  A pagina  de edição,  só poderia surgir quando o usuário clicasse no botão editar em um registro já existente, é isso que estou tentando fazer.

Comment: @RicardoPontual eu vou pesquisar como usar o ngSow e o ngHide, mas se você tiver uma sugestão de como poderia ficar o código para mim aplicar no meu projeto eu vou agradecer, mas não estou te cobrando. eu não conhecia o ngShow e o ngHide.

Comment: @RicardoPontual exite possibilidade de realizar a ocultação do link através da classe de componentes ?

Comment: Você quer dizer mudando a classe css?

Comment: @RicardoPontual, estou falando EditRestaurantComponent

Comment: Concordo com o pedro o editar so tem que existir na lista de produtos existentes.

Comment: @EduardoVargas eu não discordo de Pedro.